# Updating and adding this new Document in Firestore client-side is safe or not?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am confused over if I should be using Cloud Function in this case or keep it client-side.
I am doing a transaction (update + set). Is this safe? Can a bad actor actually cause harm to my data in DB? I know I MUST set Firestore rules to allow only authenticated users but an authenticated bad actor can still missuse it, right?

```
const refA = firestore().collection('discounts').doc(this.getSelected.discount_id);
const refB = firestore().collection('discount_reservations').doc();

const updateFunction = async transaction => {
    const [disc_amountt] = await Promise.all([
        transaction.get(refA),
    ]);

const disc_amount = disc_amountt.data().am; //getting amount field
const decrement = firestore.FieldValue.increment(-(this.state.selected_amount));
const selected_am = this.state.selected_amount;
    
    //update 
        transaction.update(refA, {
            am: decrement,
        });        

    transaction.set(refB, {
        uID: '1',
        dID: this.getSelected.discount_id,
        aR: this.state.selected_amount
    });
};

// run the transaction
firestore().runTransaction(updateFunction)
    .then(result => {
        //.....
    })
```

IF this is safe enough, doing it in Function, will it increase the performance of the app?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

*An example scenario of what I am trying to prevent*:

Here is an example scenario of my case: there are Two collections, "discounts" and "discount_reservations". When a user wants to reserve a discount, I am first checking if there is any discounts left in "discounts" collection, if yes, then I am creating a document in "discount_reservations" with the amount of discounts the user has selected. Now, the question is, what if a bad actor tries to create a document in "discount_reservations" collection even though there is NO discounts left in "discounts" collection ?!Can I prevent this using security rules?

Comment: I gave a broad explanation of the considerations below. Beyond that you'll need to specify what "safe" and "safe enough" mean for your scenario. Similar for what "increase the performance" means in numbers. Without clear definitions of what value of "safe" and "performance" you are looking for/concerned about, it'll be hard to say more than what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Your security rules should only allow the operations that you want to allow on your data. If you pay attention to crafting your security rules, you can secure large parts of your app with only security rules.

Essentially: you'll duplicate some of your business logic between your client-side code, and your server-side security rules. You'll want to have the logic in the client-side code, because that helps the user submit the right data to the database. But you **must** also have it in the **server-side security rules**, because you can't trust that all operations come from your own code.

In practice many developers find it hard to get started with security rules, so they implement their back-end functionality in Cloud Functions or another server-side API. This is a valid approach, but it just means that you're now duplicating your business logic between client-side code and **server-side code**. This may be more familiar, since both sides are now regular code (and in your case both are even in JavaScript), but you're still duplicating the logic between client and server.

So it's a trade-off you will have to make for yourself, between the more familiar paradigm of "running server-side code to ensure the data is correct and the user is authorized" versus the model with security rules. Both can be used to secure almost any scenario, and I often see a mix of both in large-scale projects.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation! Here is an example scenario of my case: there are Two collections, "discounts" and "discount_reservations". When a user wants to reserve a discount, I am first checking if there is any discounts left in "discounts" collection, if yes, then I am creating a document in "discount_reservations" with the amount of discounts the user has selected. Now, the question is, what if a bad actor tries to create a document in "discount_reservations" collection even though there is NO discounts left in "discounts" collection ?!Can I prevent this using security rules?

Comment: It sounds like that would be checkable in security rules, with a `get()` of the `discounts` document in the write rule of the `discount_reservations` document.